# Display no overalapping texts inside nested circles on fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to display text (number in my case) inside of **5 nested circles on fabricjs canvas**
But because the circles are nested inside each other and the text positions are the same as the circles positions texts are **overlapping each other** therefore i try to shift the text to the left to a certain amount of pixels but the results are not what i want.
Here is the snippets.

```js
(function()
{
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabricCanvas', {selection: false});
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

      drawRectangle();
      drawCircles()
      
    });

    function drawRectangle()
    {
        const rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 200,
          top: 100,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          fill: 'green',
          angle: 0,
          padding: 0,
          class: 'rectangle',
          opacity: 0.6,
          originX:'left',
          originY:'top'
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    }
    
    

    function drawCircles()
    {
         let my_radius = 65;

         for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
                  
                let circle =  new fabric.Circle({
                    left: 300,
                    top: 200,
                    radius: my_radius,
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    stroke: '#000',
                    fill: '#cca',
                    originX:'center',
                    originY:'center'
                });
                  let text_shift = circle.left + 0; //change 60 to 0 to ses the results
                  const text = new fabric.Text((i + 1).toString(), {
                    left: (i !== 4) ? text_shift : circle.left,
                    top: circle.top,
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fill: 'white',
                    originX: 'center',
                    originY: 'center'
                    
                });

                  const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
                    left: circle.left,
                    top: circle.top,
                    originX: 'center',
                    originY: 'center',
                    selectable: false,
                  
                });

                canvas.add(group);

                my_radius -= 10;
         }
    }

    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="fabricCanvas" width="500" height="400" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Is this what you want [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt0p6eyg/)?

Comment: Exactly mate! I appreciate a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the right cornor position you can add circle radius to center position.

`left: circle.left + circle.radius - 5,`

***DEMO***

```js
(function() {
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabricCanvas', {
    selection: false
  });
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
  drawRectangle();
  drawCircles()

  function drawRectangle() {
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 200,
      top: 100,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      fill: 'green',
      angle: 0,
      padding: 0,
      class: 'rectangle',
      opacity: 0.6,
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top'
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
  }

  function drawCircles() {
    let my_radius = 65;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 300,
        top: 200,
        radius: my_radius,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        stroke: '#000',
        fill: '#cca',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
      });
      let text_shift = circle.left + 60; //change 60 to 0 to ses the results
      const text = new fabric.Text((i + 1).toString(), {
        left: circle.left + circle.radius - 5,//5px padding,else use text width
        top: circle.top,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 10,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'

      });

      const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text], {
        left: circle.left,
        top: circle.top,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false,
      });
      canvas.add(group);
      my_radius -= 10;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="fabricCanvas" width="500" height="400" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```